# ajax の then の function 中から 返り値を受け取りたい

Tags: php, jquery, ajax

Ajax(jQuery) で then または done 内の function からの返り値を、then 以降の後続のプログラムで使用したいのですが、上手くいきません。
result.then 自体を return  してみたり、色々してみましたのですが、、、恥ずかしながらわかりません。

Ajax 自体の通信はできている前提です。
恐れ入りますが、どなたかご教示いただけましたら幸いです。

以下、省略したコードです。

```
<script src="../js/jquery/jquery-3.3.1.min.js"></script>

<script>
function ajax_func(post){
        return $.ajax({
        type: 'POST',
        url: 'ajax.php',
        cache: false,
        dataType: 'json',
        data: {
            'greeting':post
        }
        })
    }

var post = 'Hi';
console.log(post);
var result = ajax_func(post);

result.then(
    function(data){
        console.log(data);
        if(data != ""){
            return true; // (1) このtrue を受け取りたい
        }
    }
)
//(2) true を受け取った処理を書きたい

</script>
```

ajax.php

```
<?php
header("Access-Control-Allow-Origin: *");

if (isset($_POST)){
    echo json_encode('Hello');
}
```

返り値　は　`// (1) このtrue を受け取りたい`　の部分で、
書きたい後続処理は、　`//(2) true を受け取った処理を書きたい`　の部分です。

類似と思われる質問も確認しましたが、
いまいちピンと来ていません。

[Ajaxの返り値を取得する](https://ja.stackoverflow.com/questions/19395/ajax%e3%81%ae%e8%bf%94%e3%82%8a%e5%80%a4%e3%82%92%e5%8f%96%e5%be%97%e3%81%99%e3%82%8b)

Answer (score 1):

同じように`then`で繋げば良いです。

```js
      result
        .then(function (data) {
          console.log(data);
          if (data != "") {
            return true; // (1) このtrue を受け取りたい
          }
        })
        .then(function (retVal) {
          //(2) true を受け取った処理を書きたい
          console.log("retVal: " + retVal);
        });
```

[jQuery.ajax() > The jqXHR Object](https://api.jquery.com/jQuery.ajax/#jqXHR) にある通り、 [`Promise`](https://developer.mozilla.org/ja/docs/Web/JavaScript/Reference/Global_Objects/Promise) という形式です。

Answer (score 0):

こちらの１番の方法で自己解決しました。
もし回答を準備していた方がいらっしゃいましたら、大変失礼いたしました。

[jQueryのajax()を利用すると返り値をとりたいときのやり方 - Qiita](https://qiita.com/katsukii/items/bd64efcf4f070d77c028)